# Why do my automatic weights affect areas that aren't close to the bone?

Tags: rigging, bones

So I made an automatic mesh with a very similar character and it worked almost flawlessly. The main differences are that the other character had posable lips, whiskers, a bone for a sword sheath and a tail connected to the root.
[image: Character Bones]

However whenever I set the Automatic weights.
[image: It looks normal]

[image: And now It's playdoh]
I have normalized the faces, set the rest position and tried envelope weights.

Does anyone know what could have went wrong? I don't know how to properly make weights from scratch.

Comment: maybe try to re-parent but with a T pose?

Comment: If you go to edit mode, you can select all the verticies you don't want affected and remove them from the vertex group (the group should have the same name as the bone), that should be a quick and easy fix. But you will probably still need to adjust the weights in weight paint mode.